# Query plan looks good, but query slow

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a hierarchical representation and to model the tree structure, path enumeration is used. Despite the query plan to be optimized and the query itself being straightforward, it takes 4 seconds for the query to execute. However, when I remove sorting, query is fast, but I need that sort.

Basically, the query should return the relevant top parents whose children satisfy certain criteria.

Here is the link to the query and query plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1njIuPRT

```
SELECT TOP 50 Id
FROM   Site root
WHERE  Archive = 288
       AND TypeId IN( 1 )
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   Site ch
                   WHERE  ch.[path] LIKE concat(root.Path, '%')
                          AND ch.Commercial = 0
                          AND ch.Archive = 288)
ORDER  BY root.Score DESC
```

[image]

Comment: Definitely looks like an unexpectedly high CPU time to sort 6,718 rows - what is the datatype of `Path` and of `Score`?

Comment: @MartinSmith Path (nvarchar(300),null), Score (decimal(28,10), null).

Comment: Wonder if it might be burning CPU evaluating the `LikeRange` expressions for some reason

Comment: I don't think that's the case. If it were, it should be visible in the actual execution plan.  I have an index on Path column and once I remove sorting, query executes extremely fast.

Comment: Evaluation of expressions in compute scalars is often deferred. So the expressions may be being evaluated in the context of the sort operator. Difficult to envisage why sorting 6.7k rows can possibly take 4 seconds of CPU time on its own. How long does `SELECT Id, Path FROM   Site root WHERE  Archive = 288 AND TypeId = 1 ORDER  BY Score DESC` take?

Comment: It takes only 10ms and I'm totally confused now. :/

Comment: Is this something you can repro easily by creating a new `#Site` table (with same indexing, datatypes, and collations as the original) and copying the 6718 rows into it? If that repros it can you produce the same with synthetic data that you can add to the question?

Comment: Agreed with Martin, please try to reproduce on a site like  [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk) which you can then share in your Post and we can take a closer look at. 4s to sort so little of rows doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I was preparing a script that I would upload to dbfiddle.uk, I tried running it locally on a new database, it has 60,000 rows and the query runs too fast… even without an index. Worth mentioning when I changed **like concat( root.Path,'%')** to **like root.Path** in the original database, query is incorrect but extremely fast. I guess like predicate with concat function is bottleneck.

Comment: What are the values in `Path` like? Is this actually binary data?

Comment: it just represents tree-like structure of nested data using the path enumeration e.g. 1/2/3/

Comment: What collation are you using? But anyway if you can't provide a repro to us you can use Windows performance recorder or similar to see what the CPU time is being spent on as I did

Comment: Regarding your question about collation: Czech_CI_AS is used. This is managed version of SQL Server so I can't use Windows performance, but I'm pretty confident that like operator is bottleneck of the query. So, I guess nothing can be done to make this query faster?

Comment: With `Czech_CI_AS` collation and 6718 rows with path = N'1/2/3/' I couldn't reproduce the poor sort performance with the example query in my answer. But also as the slow bit of the plan is before it does anything except select the 6718 rows from the table and sort them I think the evaluation of the range start and end for the seek must be the reason. Is there any possibility the values have unexpected characters in them? Does this return anything? `SELECT Path
FROM Site
WHERE PATINDEX('%[^/0123456789]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2, Path) > 0
AND Archive = 288 AND TypeId = 1`

Comment: If you have path = N'1/2/3/' , it works very fast. I can confirm that. *Is there any possibility the values have unexpected characters in them?* Nope, just string of integers separated by slash. I replaced **ch.[path] LIKE concat(root.Path, '%')** with **PATINDEX(root.Path +  '%', ch.Path) > 0** and the query is waaay faster dude. Thank you! Here's the link to the new query plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJA1GAOCa What do you think, does it look good to you? I'm a little bit concerned it uses table spool. :/

Comment: Do all the paths end with `/`? If so then could try `SELECT TOP 50 Id FROM   Site root WHERE  Archive = 288 AND TypeId = 1 AND Path IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM   Site ch WHERE  ch.[path] >= root.Path AND ch.[path] < LEFT(root.path, LEN(root.path)-1) + ':' AND ch.Commercial = 0 AND ch.Archive = 288) ORDER  BY root.Score DESC`

Comment: Could try forcing the evaluation before the sort using `OUTER APPLY` like this `SELECT TOP 50 Id FROM Site root OUTER APPLY (SELECT concat(root.Path, '%') ) v(pathLike) WHERE  Archive = 288 AND TypeId IN = 1 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Site ch WHERE ch.[path] LIKE v.pathLike AND ch.Commercial = 0 AND ch.Archive = 288) ORDER  BY root.Score DESC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4 seconds of CPU time to sort 6,718 rows certainly seems excessive but my supposition is that this time was in fact spent evaluating the values in the compute scalar.

I could produce something similar with **Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE Site
(
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
Archive INT,
TypeId INT, 
path nvarchar(300) collate latin1_general_cs_as,
Commercial bit,
Score decimal(28,10),
index [Test] (TypeId, Archive) INCLUDE (path, Score),
index [NonClusteredIndex-20240318-221753] (path)
)

INSERT Site (Archive, TypeId, path, Commercial, Score)
select top (6718) 
Archive = 288, 
TypeId = 1, 
path = CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(300) AS NCHAR(150)), 
Commercial = 0, 
Score = CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) +0
from sys.all_columns
```

**Query**

```
WITH root AS
(
SELECT Id, path
FROM Site
WHERE  Archive = 288
       AND TypeId IN( 1 )
ORDER BY Score DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
)
SELECT Id
FROM   root
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   Site ch WITH (FORCESEEK)
                   WHERE  ch.[path] LIKE concat(root.Path, '%')
                          AND ch.Commercial = 0
                          AND ch.Archive = 288)
```

**Execution Plan**

[image]

**Windows performance recorder output**

[image]

Windows performance recorder shows that the bulk of the CPU time is taken up inside the Sort operator's Open method when it is building the sort table and that this is roughly equally divided by the three methods

- sqltses.dll!I4LikeRangeInfoWStrImpl
- sqltses.dll!WStrLikeRangeStartWStrImpl
- sqltses.dll!WStrLikeRangeEndWStrImpl

These are defined in the compute scalar and used for the [dynamic seek](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/01/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.html).

The value inserted to the `Path` column above is quite long and randomly generated garbage. The randomly generated part of this seems more important as `path = CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(20) AS NCHAR(10))` is also pretty slow but conversely using `path = CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(150) AS CHAR(150))` to restrict the characters to more common ones is much faster.

So my conclusion is that it is possible to put stuff into an `nvarchar` column  that can considerably slow down the calculation of the correct index range to seek and that this is likely what is causing the long sort duration in your case.

The above will very likely create some strings that are invalid `ucs-2` - but I'm not sure if they alone are responsible for the slower performance.